How to async instantiate and close a shared aiohttp session in Azure Functions in Python?
I need to use an HTTP client in my Azure Function. I can use aiohttp like this (this is a minimalistic example form the MSFT documentation).
import aiohttp

import azure.functions as func

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get("URL") as response:
            return func.HttpResponse(await response.text())

    return func.HttpResponse(body='NotFound', status_code=404)

However, this creates a new session object for each request, which should be avoided, as per the aiohttp documentation, as it's an expensive operation.
My question is - how can I instantiate a session object once and share it between function calls? From the ClientSession code, it looks like __aenter__ doesn't do anything, so I could instantiate the session just by calling session = aiohttp.ClientSession(). However, where would I call __aexit__?
Or is there even a better way to instantiate and clean up global objects in Azure Functions that require async instantiation and clean-up?

Use below approach/code to instantiate a global ClientSession and achieve your requirement:

Use Session.Close() to close the session.

Code Snippet:
import asyncio
import logging
import aiohttp
import azure.functions as func

session = None

async def init_session():
    global session
    if session is None:
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    return session

async def close_session():
    global session
    if session is not None:
        await session.close()
        session = None


app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
   
    if session is None:
        await init_session()

    try:
        # Use the aiohttp session to make an HTTP request
        async with session.get('http://python.org') as response:
            data = await response.text()

        return func.HttpResponse(data, status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("An error occurred", status_code=500)

def cleanup():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(close_session())

Console Output:
(.venv) C:\Users\uname\pyfn>func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-14T11:53:44.711Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        main:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-14T11:53:48.001Z] Executing 'Functions.main' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=0b3f6040-1f92-XXXXXX-b10cd5538491)
[2024-08-14T11:53:49.055Z] Executed 'Functions.main' (Succeeded, Id=0b3f6040-1f92-442e-b826-b10cd5538491, Duration=1115ms)



This is similar to the other answer but uses globals() instead of global. Also, I recommend not ever closing the connection.
import aiohttp

import azure.functions as func

def get_session():
    if "_AIO_SESSION" not in globals():
        globals()["_AIO_SESSION"] = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    return globals()["_AIO_SESSION"]


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = get_session()
    async with client.get(URL) as response:
        return func.HttpResponse(await response.text())

    return func.HttpResponse(body='NotFound', status_code=404)

The benefit here is that you can move get_session to a shared code script and other functions can import it and use it.
As for clean-up, I wouldn't. The whole point of making it a global persistent connection is that you want to keep it open. If you were running some long running process that starts with opening a connection to get data and you don't need that connection for the rest of the script then that is where you want to make sure you close connections. In this use case you want to keep it alive forever.
